# Delete file using crontab with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, cron, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file using Laravel 4, but, with crontab.

I have created a "costume_command" with Artisan (notify). And in the "fire" method, that will execute when the command is used in cmd line, I have this:

```
public function fire()
{

   $destination = 'public/uploads/11_home.png';
   File::delete($destination);
}
```

When I use my Costume Command in the cmd line, using `php artisan notify`, everything works fine, and the file is deleted. But when I use crontab to run this "command", it wont delete the file.

I tried with other code instead of deleting a file, example, sending an email, and it both work with "cmd line" and crontab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path is correct. Try using the helper public_path() function like this:

```
<?php

public function fire ()
{
    $destination = public_path() . '/uploads/11_home.png';

    File::delete($destination);
}

?>
```

Comment: No problem, make sure to go through the API here: http://laravel.com/api/ which you can search for the helper functions. They are also listed here: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers